# stuck in replacing negative values with zero in SPSS Modeler

Tags: spss-modeler

I am trying to replace the -ve values with "0" and derive a new variable in SPSS Modeler . I am trying "Derive" node to accomplish the job using the function of "**if INDV_ASS_INC_TAMT < 0 then INDV_ASS_INC_TAMT=0 else INDV_ASS_INC_TAMT=INDV_ASS_INC_TAMT endif**" but getting the following error " **The conditional expression contains incompatible return types: Boolean and Integer"**.

I am novice SPSS Modeler User and stuck for 2 days to figure it out . Your help would much appreciated .

Snap shot in link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SooeZ.png)

[Error [][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SooeZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use "Filler node" to replace value in your Column based on condition.

https://www.ibm.com/support/producthub/icpdata/docs/content/SSQNUZ_current/wsd/nodes/filler.html